# GWT arbitrary HTML

Tags: java, gwt

In GWT how can I insert in the `onModuleLoad` method a frameset and the relative nested framesets and frames to incorporate a number of applets and other widgets and HTML?
The code snippet is: 
    public class MainEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        FrameSetElement frameSet;
        Document documento = Document.get();
        frameSet = documento.createFrameSetElement();
        frameSet.setCols("2");
        frameSet.setRows("2");
        //RootPanel.get("s").add(frameSet);
    }
    }
It don't runs, the web page remains blank! 
Could anybody help me, i am a GWT beginner. 
Thanks SaSa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with GWT's documentation of http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/dom/client/FrameSetElement.html

It would help if you posted more detailed question with code snippets and error information if any.